# node js async call in filter caused 404 error

Tags: javascript

my project based on node express.js and there is some filter process for every API call, means it will execute the filter first to do some validation and then execute the API function, like below:

```
    init: function (options) {
        self.o = options || {};
        self.add(initFilter).add(jwtFilter).add(xssFilter);
        return self.run;
    },
    add: function (fn) {
        self.filterList.push(fn);
        return self;
    },
    runNext: function (o, req, res) {
        if (self.o.next && self.o.currentFunction < self.filterList.length) {

            self.filterList[self.o.currentFunction](o, req, res, function(){
                self.o.currentFunction++;
                self.runNext(self.o, req, res);
              });
        } else {
            self.complete();
        }
    },
    run: function (req, res, next) {
        self.o.req = req, self.o.res = res, self.o.next = next, self.o.doNext = true, self.o.currentFunction = 0;
        if (self.o.next && self.o.currentFunction < self.filterList.length) {
            self.runNext(self.o, req, res);
        }
    },
    complete: function () {
        if (self.o.doNext)
            self.o.next();
    },
    o: {
        req: {},
        res: {},
        next: {},
        doNext: true,
        currentFunction: 0
    },
    filterList: [],
```

currently I'm facing a issue when executing in the filter, like below code, I use async call 'getLoginiat' to get a value from redis and compare with login info to do a validation, the function getLoginiat call the redisClient to get the data. now once a API call request come to the backend, it always return 404 error, if I comment the call to function 'getLoginiat', the same API run correctly. I'm really confused, is it related to redis or maybe there is something wrong with the function getLoginiat? can anyone advise or meet the similar issue?

```
module.exports = async (op, req, res, callback)=> {
    let jwtObj;
    var o = op || {};
    // if not login url, jwt always required
    if(req.url !== `/${app_name}/login/authenticate` && req.url !== `/${app_name}/login/authenticateForClient` && req.url !== `/${app_name}/getCsrfToken` && req.url !== `/${app_name}/adfs/postResponse` && req.url !== `/${app_name}/refreshAllRuleCategories/refreshDataByRunAllRuleCategory` && req.url !== `/${app_name}/assignWorkflowAndSurvey/assignWorkflowAndSurveyToUncompletedCases`) {
        try {
            jwtObj = jwtUtil.jwtVerify(req.cookies[jwt_name]);
        } catch (e) {
            responseHandler(res, {code: 308}, null);
        }
        if (jwtObj && jwtObj.dbUrl) {
            let login_iat = await getLoginiat(jwtObj.uGuid);
            if (jwtObj.iat != login_iat) {
                res.err[309] = codeMapping[309];
                responseHandler(res, {code: 309}, null);
            }
            let dbConnStr = getDatabaseConnectionString();
            if(db && dbConnStr && dbConnStr != jwtObj.dbUrl){
                await setDataConnections(jwtObj.dbUrl)
            }
            callback();
        }else{
            res.err[301] = codeMapping[301];
            responseHandler(res, {code: 301}, null);
            callback();
        }
    } else {
        callback();
    }
}


function setDataConnections(dbUrl) {
    __dbUtil.setConnection(dbUrl);
}

function getLoginiat(uguid) {
    return redisClient.get(uguid).then(function (result) {
        return result;
      });
}
```

below is the definition of redisClient :

```
const Redis = require('ioredis');
const redisClient = new Redis({
  host: process.env.SESSION_REDIS_HOST, 
  port: process.env.SESSION_REDIS_PORT, //6380,
  password: process.env.SESSION_REDIS_PASSWORD, 
  autoResubscribe: false,
  tls: 'true' === process.env.SESSION_REDIS_SSL, 
  retryStrategy: function (times) {
    return times < 5 ? times * 1000 : 10000;
  }
});
```

Some updates about this issue: currently there are two API call send by Promise.all, the API '/login/syncUsers' return 404 after the filter execution, I suspect this error related to the redisClient in the filter.

```
return Promise.all([this.RoleApi.getUserRoleByGuid(uGuid), this.axios.get('/login/syncUsers')]);
```

When I tested to put only one API call in Promise.all, the API call return successful, although run with the same filter(call redisClient in the filter), really don't know what's wrong with this..

```
return Promise.all([this.axios.get('/login/syncUsers')]);
```

Comment: Last I checked, Express (v4) did not have first-class support for async route handlers or middleware. You can definitely make it work, but you'll have to write custom code. IIRC, I created a wrapper for all my route handlers that bridged the sync/async gap. You will need to do something similar.